# Enforcing a separate session for WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, session

I'm testing my WCF service, and I would like to send two (virtually) parallel requests to my WCF service. However, my `InstanceMode = PerSession` and it's fine the way it is, I don't want to change the service behavior.

However, my question is - does creating two proxy client objects enforce separate sessions? Or is there something else that should be done to send the two requests via different client sessions?
I created a sample C# console application to test this:

```
MyService client = new MyService();
MyService  client1 = new MyService();
client.GetResultsAsync();
client1.GetResultsAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame that your requirements prohibit using the primary feature that would solve this problem - namely `InstanceMode = PerCall`.

Per [WCF Service Behaviors - Instance and Concurrency Management](https://web.archive.org/web/20120520105959/http://mkdot.net/community/mknetug/b/dejan/archive/2008/04/29/wcf-service-behaviors-instance-and-concurrency-management.aspx):

Using the default settings of `InstanceMode = PerSession` and `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single` then "it's easy to make a conclusion that every client has it's own session executed only on one thread per client."

Per [Programming WCF Services - 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805494.do) Page 177:

"When the client creates a new proxy to a service configured as a *sessionful service*, the client gets a new dedicated service instance that is independent of all other instances of the same service"

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that the default InstanceMode is PerSession: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx